# Improve merging multiple CSV data with LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have four CSV files, each with 400k-880k rows and a couple dozen columns. One is the master file, the other three contain ancillary data. All files contain time stamps, but are not synced. The three ancillary files have 4x the number of rows due to a higher sample rate.

For each data row in the master I am finding the nearest applicable time stamp in the ancillary files like this, with the idea to get the ancillary data for that time and merge it into the master data:

```
var valueJustBeforeMasterTime = from row in dtAncillary.Rows
              where masterTimeInTicks - DateTime.ParseExact(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Substring(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Length - 15),
                "HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks <= 10e5 &&
               masterTimeInTicks - DateTime.ParseExact(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Substring(rowFB["ANCIL_TIME"].Length - 15),
                "HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks >= 0
                                                  select row.Values;

var beforeNow = valueJustBeforeMasterTime.Last();
```

This is turning out to be an expensive operation, taking a long time, given that I need to do this ~600 times for the data subset. I read about compiled LINQ queries to speed things up, but am unsure how to approach that. Should I move away from LINQ for this particular need?

Comment: Have you tried [Plinq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try [PLINK.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var valueJustBeforeMasterTime = from row in dtAncillary.Rows.AsParallel()
          where masterTimeInTicks - DateTime.ParseExact(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Substring(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Length - 15),
            "HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks <= 10e5 &&
           masterTimeInTicks - DateTime.ParseExact(row["ANCIL_TIME"].Substring(rowFB["ANCIL_TIME"].Length - 15),
            "HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Ticks >= 0
                                              select row.Values;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It only helped marginally, even though I have a multicore CPU. I suspect with the amount of data involved, this is just a slow process.